# Range of dates with minutes

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to create a series of dates from 01/01/2010 to 01/02/2010 with the minutes at uneven distances, like so:

```
2010  1  1  00  00  00
2010  1  1  00  20  00
2010  1  1  00  30  00
2010  1  1  00  40  00
2010  1  1  01  00  00
2010  1  1  01  20  00
2010  1  1  01  30  00
2010  1  1  01  40  00

...
2010  2  1  00  00  00
```

So at minute 00, minute 20, minute 30 and minute 40, every hour until the end date. I have found help in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621409/print-dates-in-date-range-linux 
But I am unable to add minutes to it, let alone spaces instead of '-' and the uneven steps. This is my code so far, which does not work:

```
startdate=2010-01-01-00-00-00
enddate=2010-02-01-00-00-00

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    echo "$curr"
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S --date "$curr +10 minutes" )
done
```

How do I create the output above at those intervals with spaces inbetween?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it :

```
$ date -d '2010-01-01 00:00:00' +%s
1262300400
$ date -d '2010-02-01 00:00:00' +%s
1264978800

$ for timestamp in {1262300400..1264978800..600}; do date -d @"$timestamp" '+%Y %m %d %H %M %S'; done | grep -Ev '[15]0 00$'
```

What `grep -Ev '[15]0 00$'` does :

- `grep` itself selects line(s) matching a set of conditions described by its parameters
- `-v` : select lines that DO NOT match the parameters
- `-E` : declares that the pattern we'll try to match is an 'Extended regular expression' (it was actually NOT required here - my mistake)
- `[15]0 00$` : a regular expression saying "select lines ending with "1 or 5" then "zero" then "space" then "double zero". This matches the "10" and "50" lines, which are removed thanks to the `-v` described above.

Comment: I still need to delete the minute 10 and minute 50. How do I do that?

Comment: @Jellyse Ooops, I missed that point in your question. I've just edited my answer.